# Counts and Loops in C#

Tags: c#, loops

This seems like a really simple thing to do but I cant't seem to get my ahead around it. I have 10 documents entitled 1.txt to 10.txt. I just want to count the number of lines in each doc and end up with the final summation of the line counts.

This is where I got to.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        int lineCount = File.ReadLines(@i + ".txt").Count();
        lineCount += lineCount; 
        Console.WriteLine("Total IDs: " + lineCount);
    }
```

**UPDATE**
My docs have carriage returns at the bottom of them which I do not want to include in the count.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are reinitializing `lineCount` every time.  Change it like so:

```
int lineCount = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    lineCount += File.ReadLines(@i + ".txt").Count();
}
Console.WriteLine("Total IDs: " + lineCount);
```

This way you don't reinitialize `lineCount` every time, and you are simply adding the `Count` to it for each iteration.

Comment: Part 2 to the problem: Its counting carriage returns in my document. How can I prevent that?

Comment: For the carriage returns, add "lineCount--;" in the for loop.

Comment: @seeker: There's got to be a better way to ignore carriage returns, that doesn't assume they're always there.  I don't know C#, or I would suggest something.

Comment: A better way than just ignoring it?

Comment: Yeah, there is. If you wanted to just not assume each file ended in a carriage return, that would require him writing his own line counting for loop. Inside his current for loop, he would do something like this: string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(i + ".txt"); for(int i = 1; i <= lines.Length; i++){ if(lines[i].Equals(@"\r\n") && i == lines.Length){/* do nothing */} else{lineCount++;}}

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, if he knows for a fact that each file ends in a carriage return, then just adding "lineCount--;" is the better way to go. So both are good, depending on the knowledge you have. If you want to play it safe, then use my second one.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared lineCount inside of the loop, so it is destroyed and created again after each iteration, i.e., you are only seeing the last result.  Declare lineCount outside the scope of the loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

`lineCount += lineCount;` is the same as `lineCount *= 2;`; is that what you intended?